# React js fetch all data from a paginated api with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am working on a react app for what is going to an editing tool for internal use. I have a use-case where I need to get all the items that are paginated. The thing is that all params our backend. has is limit & offset. But there are no response headers that indicate what page I'm on currently. Anyone with an idea of what I should change with my code to get all items so I can run skip and take until I get all the items & how do I update `skip` & `take` asynchronous so the next request is updated with the right params? With class component, I would use setState callback?

my code

```
 const fetchItems = async () => {
    try {
      const items: any = await itemsService.getItems({
        skip: 0,
        take: 50,
      })

      setItems(items)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here in this case you should mainatain loadMoreFlag as state of component
like

```
     const [hasLoadMore,setHasLoadMore]=useState(true);//assumeing it will have load more for very first time
```

after that you can use it in fetch call like this

```
  const fetchItems = async () => {
            if(!hasLoadeMore)return;
            try {
                const items: any = await itemsService.getItems({
                  skip: 0,
                  take: 50,
                })
            if(items!==null && items !==undefined){
               setHasLoadMore(true);
               setItems(items)  
            }
            else{
              setHasLoadMore(false);//if you are requesting the last+1 page y ou will not recive any items
              }
             } catch (error) {
               console.log(error)
            }
         }
```

**EDIT**

for answer to your comment about using skip and take:

> How can I make the equivalent logic with react hooks?

you can declaer  both inside function component and use with hooks like

```
      const [skip,setSkip]=useState(0);
      const [take,setTake]=useState(50);
```

now you can use them when needed.

Comment: How do I update skip & take asynchronous so next requests is updated with the right skip & take params? With class, I would use the callback func from setState?

Comment: How can I make the equivalent logic with react hooks?

Comment: Yeah, I know but my question is how can I make sure that setSkip & setTake are updated async in the function or the function component so I don't make duplicate requests with the same skip & take params?

Comment: if am not getting wrong , you want to make sure both are updated at same time,
as updating it one by one make two time updates ,if its right,then  you can use a single object containing both and then update it